# How to execute http-requests with angular universal prerender?

Tags: angular, http, httpclient

I just added an angular universal prerender to my app by running `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` by following this [tutorial](https://trilon.io/blog/angular-universal-v9-whats-new)

In my application I am making two simple http calls on `app.component` so it runs when application starts.

```
  private getDataOne(name) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/one');
  }

  private getDataTwo(name) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/two');
  }
```

However when I prerender my application with this command `npm run prerender` it seems it still calling the server. So I wonder how would you execute http so when you server prerendered app it would use existing value and no execute http?

I've tried to put my endpoint to `server.ts` but it is didn't help

```
server.get('http://localhost:3000/api/**', (req, res) => {});
```

also I tried that but no luck

```
  server.get('http://localhost:3000/api/one', (req, res) => res.json());
  server.get('http://localhost:3000/api/two', (req, res) => res.json());
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: The fact that this question was asked more than 3 years back and still unanswered, is quite sad. This is still not clear in the official docs as well on how to handle such async api call on which the view depends. The closest I got is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582274/how-can-i-force-angular-universal-to-pre-render-content-from-an-external-api)