# Angular Prerendering is not waiting to complete firebase request

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I am using Angular PreRendering with Firebase. Angular doesnt wait to complete the firebase call and it generates html without content.

is there way I can force angular to wait till firebase complete the requests.

I see a solution in the below link, but not sure how I can implement for firebase.

[How can I force Angular Universal to pre-render content from an external api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582274/how-can-i-force-angular-universal-to-pre-render-content-from-an-external-api)

Here is my server.ts file.

````
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';```


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582274/how-can-i-force-angular-universal-to-pre-render-content-from-an-external-api
````

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem where my page was changing before data could be sent to Firebase. I simply let the program sit for a second:

```
 setTimeout(() => {YOUR CODE GOES HERE}, 500);
```

Comment: Where exactly I need to add this?

Comment: @Vijay It gives a little bit of time for the data to go through to Firebase.